# windows 11 attach more than one vhd system cannot find the file specified

Tags: virtualbox, windows-11, vhd

I created a couple of VHD images of existing partitions. The important thing is they don't contain a partition table, just an NTFS image. I'm trying to attach them to a running Windows 11 Pro. For some reason only one image works at time. An attempt to attach the other image results no volume, no Label, no mount points.

[image]

System events:

```
Acer
Volume \\?\Volume{00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} (\Device\HarddiskVolume31) is healthy.  No action is needed.
...
New7
Volume new7 (\Device\HarddiskVolume32) is healthy.  No action is needed.
```

[image]
System events:

```
Volume \\?\Volume{00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} (\Device\HarddiskVolume33) is healthy.  No action is needed.
...
Volume Acer (\Device\HarddiskVolume34) is healthy.  No action is needed.
```

```
[root@archiso /]# lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   FSVER            LABEL           UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda
├─sda1 ntfs                      PQSERVICE       18F8B496F8B4739A
├─sda2 ntfs                      SYSTEM RESERVED A848B53248B4FFDC
├─sda3 ntfs                      Acer            8A46D34B46D336A3
├─sda4
└─sda5 ntfs                      new7            C83C3CDB3C3CC66A

[root@archiso /]# VBoxManage convertfromraw /dev/sda3 ssd250p3.vhd --format=VHD
[root@archiso /]# VBoxManage convertfromraw /dev/sda5 ssd250p5.vhd --format=VHD
```